# Difficulty Sorting Tuples with itemgetter

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I'm new to Python as the screen name attests.  I was attempting to sort a list of tuples, think (x,y) pairs in a list and ran into a problem.  My goal is to sort the list of tuples by the x variables in ascending order primarily but then sort

I investigated the wiki on HowToSort at http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/ and thought I would try the **operator** module and the **itemgetter** function as a key.

The simple sorted() function can sort the tuple fine, but when you want one index ascending and one ascending, I'm lost.  Here is the code:

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

ItemList = [(1,7),(2,1),(1,5),(1,1)]
# Want list sorted with X values descending, then y values ascending
# expected [(2, 1), (1, 1), (1,5), (1, 7)]

print
print '  Input:', ItemList
print 'Output1:',sorted(ItemList, reverse = True)
print 

print '  Input:', ItemList
print 'Output2:', sorted(ItemList, key = itemgetter(-0,1))
print
print ' WANTED:', '[(2, 1), (1, 1), (1,5), (1, 7)]'
```

with the following output:

```
  Input: [(1, 7), (2, 1), (1, 5), (1, 1)]
Output1: [(2, 1), (1, 7), (1, 5), (1, 1)]

  Input: [(1, 7), (2, 1), (1, 5), (1, 1)]
Output2: [(1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7), (2, 1)]

 WANTED: [(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7)]
```

I obviously, do not understand the itemgetter function, so any help would be appreciated on that.

Also, any ideas on how to do the two sort on (x,y) pairs?  I am hoping to avoid a lambda solution but I'm sure that's where this is going.  Thanks.

Comment: How is `[(2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 7)]` sorted with `x`-values descending?

Comment: Your WANTED output makes no sense. I think you mistyped and meant `[(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7)]` instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-0` is *the same thing* as `0`. More-over, negative indices have a different meaning to `itemgetter()`; it does *not* mean that the values are negated.

Use a `lambda` instead:

```
sorted(ItemList, key=lambda item: (-item[0], item[1]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> ItemList = [(1,7),(2,1),(1,5),(1,1)]
>>> sorted(ItemList, key=lambda item: (-item[0], item[1]))
[(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 7)]
```

Negative indices take items from the *end* of a sequence:

```
>>> end = itemgetter(-1)
>>> end([1, 2, 3])
3
```

The `itemgetter()` will never modify the retrieved item, certainly not negate it.

Note that `itemgetter()` is only a convenience method, you do not *have* to use it and for more complex sorting orders, a custom function or lambda is the better choice.

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you!  I knew it was a _lambda_.  I have to stop fearing the **lambda**!!

Comment: @NewatPython: Any callable will do, but a `lambda` is more convenient here. A function could serve the same purpose.